# Find the sum of an array of consecutive numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

How would I find the sum of of consecutive numbers like:

- 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
- 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 24

when I only know the first, last, and the increment between numbers?

Here is what it should look like:

```js
function sumOfCon(f, l, i) {
  //...
}
console.log(sumOfCon(1, 3, 1));
console.log(sumOfCon(3, 9, 2));
```

I don't have a "what I've tried" because I posted an answer below.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when someone passes in numbers that don't match up perfectly, like `sumOfCon(3,5,3);` ?

Comment: Then it doesn't execute the function.

Comment: Use a while loops?

Answer (score 1):

with check it will look like this

```
function sumOfCon(f, l, i) {
  const parts = (l - f) / i
  if (Math.floor(parts) !== parts) return undefined
  return (l + f) * (parts / 2 + 0.5) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sumOfCon(first, last, inc) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = first; i <= last; i = i + inc) {
      sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfCon(1, 3, 1));
console.log(sumOfCon(3, 9, 2));
console.log(sumOfCon(3, 5, 3));
```

Comment: What happens when someone inputs (3, 5, 3)?

Comment: @Yousername, it will return 3. IMO, if you say give consecutive numbers from 3 to 5 with increment, it should be "3" right?. If your requirement is do not count 3 then, we can update function with the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to add the numbers. (explanation below)

It doesn't work when the numbers are like 1 + 3 + ... 8 because that is mostly impossible.

```js
function sumOfCon(f, l, i) { //first, last, increment
  if ((f + l) % i !== 0) return sumOfCon(f, l - ((f + l) % i), i);
  return (f + l) * (l - f + i) / (2 * i);
  /*a simplified version is: (l*l-f*f+i*(f+l))/(2*i)
   **Explanation to the function**
   *For 1, 5, 1, the numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
   *1 + 6 is 7, and so is 2 + 5, and 3 + 4.
   *This means that multiplying (1 + 6) by 3 gives us the answer.
   *You can get 3 by taking the number of numbers and dividing by 2.
   *But if the increment is not 1, like 5, 7, 9, it is trickier.
   *First, you add 5 + 9 = 14.
   *14 × 1.5 gives us the answer, because there are 3 numbers and 3
   *divided by 2 is 1.5
   *You can get the amount of numbers by doing (l - f + 1) if the
   *increment is 1.
   *If the increment is not 1, you can do (l - f + i) / i.
   *Finally, you divide by 2 to get the sum.
  */
}
console.log(sumOfCon(1, 3, 1));
console.log(sumOfCon(3, 9, 2));
console.log(sumOfCon(0, 26, 2));
console.log(sumOfCon(1, 6, 2)); // 1 + 3 + 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sumOfCon= (...a) => a.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)

sumOfCon(1,2,3) //6
sumOfCon(1,2,3,4,5) //15
```

watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKmtUW9VKVA&t=11s